# When upload the font show security Error

Tags: wordpress, fonts

When I try to upload the font in WordPress dashboard It's showing me the security error. I want to upload the TTF, EOT and other fonts in wp dashboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to allow MIME type in the dashboard. Below is the code you need to add in function.php file.

```
  add_filter('upload_mimes', 'add_custom_upload_mimes');
  function add_custom_upload_mimes($existing_mimes) {
    $existing_mimes['woff'] = 'application/x-font-woff';
    $existing_mimes['ttf'] = 'application/x-font-ttf';
    $existing_mimes['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';
    $existing_mimes['eot'] = 'application/vnd.ms-fontobject';
    return $existing_mimes;
  }
```

You can add more mime type in the array.

Comment: Can I add image mime type in the array.

Comment: Yes, you can add any file. please note you need to specify the MIME type.

Comment: In functions.php file inside the theme folder.